# Gitlab Pages custom domain SSL

Tags: ssl, https, gitlab

I'm trying to add TLS/SSL to my custom domain on Gitlab. Currently it says my site is available at https://yodel.co, but when I go there it says the certificate is invalid. How do I go about validating the certificate?

In the [docs](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html#secure-your-custom-domain-website-with-tls) (also pictured) it says there are keys to add from your admin when setting up a new domain. However I'm not sure where to get these keys as I am the admin.

**My Gitlab Pages**
[image: My Pages]

**Gitlab docs screenshot**
[image: Documentation says there's keys to add?]

Comment: It belongs to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Got it, I've posted there: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95154/gitlab-pages-custom-domain-ssl

Comment: This has been solved, more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889365/gitlab-pages-daemon-where-is-home-git

Comment: Your site is available under http://yodel.co/ until you add a certificate to it. Which cert have you issued for that?

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed this was an old issue :p

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify, 3 years later, your process by using GitLab 12.1 (July 2019).

It comes with "[**Automatic HTTPS for Pages with Let's Encrypt**](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/07/22/gitlab-12-1-released/#automatic-https-for-pages-with-lets-encrypt)":

> In 12.1, Pages users that add a new custom domain can enable “Automatic certificate management using Let’s Encrypt”.
>   With this setting configured, GitLab automatically procures certs from Let’s Encrypt, provisions them to your custom domain in GitLab, keeps track of the expiration date and automatically renews your certs.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/12_1/lets-encrypt-feature.png]

See more at "[GitLab Pages integration with Let's Encrypt](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/lets_encrypt_integration.html)", from [issue 28996](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28996):

> The GitLab Pages integration with Let’s Encrypt (LE) allows you to use LE certificates for your Pages website with custom domains without the hassle of having to issue and update them yourself; GitLab does it for you, out-of-the-box.
>
> Your selections can be set on a per-domain basis to accommodate varying users and requirements.

---